# Match two matrices by columns

Tags: r

I have two matrices that looks like this:

A

> ```
> ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC    ColumnD     
>    A         D         N          F            
>    DF        N         A          S    
>    P         F         K          l      
>    qw        AS        O          W    
>              n         H          Q      
>                        D          E
> ```

B

> ```
>   ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC    ColumnD     
>      A         DH        K          FS            
>     np         N         A           S    
>     AS         Q         O          lm      
>      P         n         N          WE    
>                AS        PV          Q      
>                          NQ          E
> ```

I would like a third matrix C containing the common elements column by column between the two matrices. 
I tried to do this work by using R but it seems impossible since the two matrices are too large: ~5000 rows and 1500 columns. The two matrices have the same number of columns ad the same column names.

Can anyone help me please?

Best

Desired output: 
C

> ```
> ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC    ColumnD     
>    A         N         N          S            
>    P         AS        A          Q    
>              n         K          E      
>                        O
> ```

Comment: Can you give your desired output for your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(stringi)
#Here `A` and `B` are "data.frames"
m1 <- stri_list2matrix( Map(`intersect`, A, B), fill='')
C <- setNames(as.data.frame(m1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), colnames(A))
C
#   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
# 1       A       N       N       S
# 2       P      AS       A       Q
# 3               n       K       E
# 4                       O
```

Or

```
lst <- lapply(rbind(A,B), function(x) x[duplicated(x)& x!=''] )
m2 <- sapply(lst, `length<-`, max(sapply(lst, length)))
m2[is.na(m2)] <- ''
as.data.frame(m2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
#1       A       N       K       S
#2       P       n       A       Q
#3              AS       O       E
#4                       N
```

Comment: I solved with "stringi" library. It works very well. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use sqlite?

In sqlite you could try something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT newtable
FROM A 
WHERE newtable Not IN (SELECT DISTINCT newtable FROM B)
```

it shoulnt be too much hassle to create a .db file

Note: if you're running linux you have sqlite or sqlite3 installed already